# Why working permanent alias in hyper terminal doesn't work in vs-code bash terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code, git-bash

I'm on Windows 10 machine and I just installed VS-Code to use instead of Atom. I tried to use permanent alias in VS-Code Bash Terminal which I had created & was working fine in Hyper Terminal,   but it doesn't work in VS-Code terminal. Why is that & How can I fix it ?

I have

```sh
alias mongod="/c/Program\ files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/mongod.exe"
alias mongo="/c/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/mongo.exe"
```

in my '.bash_profile' file

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VS-Code terminal, try and check your alias is still defined:

```
alias mongod
cd ~
more .bash_profile
```

You will then see if said alias is still there in that VSCode environment.

If it is: do a `source ~/.bash_profile`, and the alias should be operational.

see also "[Why `~/.bash_profile` is not getting sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/121073/5470)"

> - `~/.bash_profile` is only sourced by bash when started in interactive login mode.
> - When you open a terminal, the terminal starts bash in (non-login) interactive mode, which means it will source `~/.bashrc`.

So in your case, move those alias definitions to `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: It is in the file.

Comment: @tseevag OK, then what do you see when you type `mongod` (the alias)?

Comment: Does `alias mongod` returns the definition of the alias? If not, can you try again after typing `source ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @tseevag Great! I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @tseevag I have added to the answer the reason why those aliases were not active by default.